# scala specs2 & junit in eclipse => test classes not recognized

Tags: eclipse, scala, junit, specs2, spray

I have a spray project, in scala, and in my project I have specs2 tests which worked fine when I was using eclipse on a macbook.
But I have bought a windows 8 computer and reinstalled all the stuff and since the tests are not recognized by eclipse.

Here are the versions:

sbt      : 0.13.1
java     : 8
eclipse  : 4.3.2 for java developpers
scala    : 2.10.4
scala-ide: 3.0.2

Here is a sample code that does not work:

```
package com.example

import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.specs2.runner.JUnitRunner

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class HelloWorldSpec extends Specification {

  "The 'Hello world' string" should {
    "contain 11 characters" in {
      "Hello world" must have size(11)
    }
    "start with 'Hello'" in {
      "Hello world" must startWith("Hello")
    }
    "end with 'world'" in {
      "Hello world" must endWith("world")
    }
  }
}
```

here is the build.sbt config file:

```
organization  := "com.example"

version       := "0.1"

scalaVersion  := "2.10.3"

scalacOptions := Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-encoding", "utf8")

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val akkaV = "2.3.0"
  val sprayV = "1.3.1"
  Seq(
        "io.spray"            %   "spray-servlet" % sprayV,
        "io.spray"            %   "spray-routing" % sprayV,
        "org.eclipse.jetty"   %   "jetty-webapp"  % "9.1.0.v20131115" % "container",
        "org.eclipse.jetty"   %   "jetty-plus"    % "9.1.0.v20131115" % "container",
        "org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016" % "container"   artifacts Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar"),
        "io.spray"            %   "spray-testkit" % sprayV % "test",
        "com.typesafe.akka"   %%  "akka-actor"    % akkaV,
        "com.typesafe.akka"   %%  "akka-testkit"  % akkaV % "test",
        "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.3.10" % "test",
    "com.typesafe.slick" % "slick_2.10" % "2.0.0",
        "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "0.6.0",
        "org.xerial" % "sqlite-jdbc" % "3.7.2",
        "org.quartz-scheduler" % "quartz" % "2.2.1",
    "io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.2.5",
    "junit" % "junit" % "4.11",
    "com.github.scala-incubator.io" %% "scala-io-core" % "0.4.2",
    "com.github.scala-incubator.io" %% "scala-io-file" % "0.4.2"
  )
}

seq(webSettings: _*)

seq(Twirl.settings: _*)

scalacOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Yrangepos")

resolvers ++= Seq("snapshots", "releases").map(Resolver.sonatypeRepo)
```

the error message is : no junit test found(when I right-click on the class, and select "run with"/"scala junit test".

can you help me? Is the eclipse bundle wrong(I mean on my mac I had eclipse Java EE and not eclipse for java developers)?

thanks

EDIT:
it's resolved : I created a new launch configuration for each test class, without forgetting to specify the kind of test : scala junit 4 test.